# Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB.

When I try to connect through simple jdbc connection it works.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@chbsux0097.eu.novartis.net:1530:AD14", "xxxx", "xxxxx")
```

However, it's not working with `Spring-boot` with below error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-09 12:48:51.189 ERROR 16236 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:oracle:thin@chbsux0097.eu.novartis.net:1530:AD14
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.username=xx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@chbsux0097.eu.novartis.net:1530:AD14
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: Get rid of the `Class.forName()` line. It hasn't been needed since 2007. Note that you have already given two different versions of the classname. You don't need to know it any more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing a colon in the URL after `thin` in your config. It needs to be:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@chbsux0097.eu.novartis.net:1530:AD14
```

Note that the colon is present in your working simplified example.

Comment: spent :'( whole day yesterday and didn't notice it, yes it works now

Comment: service name has to be delimited by / not : therefore proper form is:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@chbsux0097.eu.novartis.net:1530/AD14

Comment: @Frk I'm using a colon there (for SID not service name though) and it works with ojdbc7.